# Is it possible to customize the push notification screen in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, customization

Hi I'm currently working on a chat application using XMPP framework. When a user is offline & when they receive a message, I'm sending them a push notification along with the message. Is it possible to add a "Reply" button on the push notification screen like how it is in iMessage, so that the user can reply to messages directly from the notification screen? [image: I've added the screenshot below]

Is it possible to customize the notification screen?

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Look at interactive notifications http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/

Comment: You now know what you need to research wether it is Objective-C or Swift it doesn't matter, all you need to do is google `interactive notifications objective-c` and I am sure loads of results will appear.

Comment: @sbarow: That's exactly what I'm doing. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking after Notification with actions which is available in iOS8. In [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26) you should look at the "Using Notification Actions in iOS" section

Comment: Got an idea with the link u referred. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If it helps consider upvoting. If it solves your problem consider choosing this as correct answer :)